# Hidden Edittext reading from RFID reader

Tags: android, android-edittext, rfid

I'm working with a android application and have this annoying issue :)

Log in screen:
The user log in using his token and a rfid reader connected to the tablet. 
I have a EditText field in my login layout, and the user can scan his token. Everything is working fine. But i simply don't know how to hide the EditText field, so the value from the users token don't show on the screen. I have tried to set the visibility false, but then the values is not stored in the EditText. Can someone please help me out with a best practice example. I simply want to read 8 characters from the rfid reader(or a keyboard, same princip) and be able to read this value.

Thanks
Turan

Comment: I also have similar issue. Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If your reader uses a keyboard emulation driver, intercept onKeyDown/Up in your activity to redirect them to the hidden EditText.

Also, why do you want to hide the value of the token ? if it behaves as a keyboard, using the reader on any text input field will display it.

Comment: Customer requirements. I will try with onKeyDown/Up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the EditText's input type to textPassword, so the characters are hidden? Add this attribute to the EditText in the XML:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

You could also set the layout_height and layout_width to something like 1px if you don't want the EditText visible at all. Although, that is a bit of a hacky solution.

Comment: Thanks. I will use this solution, only if i can't find a way to remove the EditText field...